# how to add a contextual box associated to a keyword?

Tags: packages, book-design

I am trying to write a book with LaTeX. I want to put contextual boxes with information (or images) associated with a keyword, like the boxes at the left on this image:

[image]

It would be amazing if LaTeX arrange the positioning of this boxes automatically... at this point, I am really lost, and I don't even know the name of this boxes.

Is there a package or a document class to achieve that? as a last resource... is there any manual way to achieve this?

Comment: `\marginpar{hello}` is standard latex but there are lots of variant packages marginnote, todnote,... and for the caption at side of image look at packages for caption formatting

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.